# How can I use filter/subset with an exception in R?

Tags: r, filter, subset

for example I have a dataset that looks this

```
print(x)



Age   Hometown     
22    New York
24    Houston
26    Ney York
27    Chicago
30    Washington
```

Question for example: The Person must be under 28 years but older than 24 years , `except` the persons hometown is New York. 
The first part of the question would I answer like this

`xnew <- subset(x, Age > 28 & Age < 24`) , but how can I solve the second part of this question?

Comment: My instinct is that you're not thinking about the problem correctly, and except is not supposed to be a programming term. Exceptions in programming are used to handle errors, and I doubt the question wants your script to throw an error if the hometown is New York. But I could be wrong.

Comment: My aim is that the first row don't get kicked out. The Solution should be Row  1,3 and 4

Comment: And also thanks to you docendo !!!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want everyone who is older than 24 and younger than 28 **or** lives in New York regardless of age.

```
xnew <- subset(x, Age > 24 & Age < 28 | Hometown == New York)
```

Comment: OMG , I`m just an ..... . Many thanks!!!! This was what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
xnew <- subset(x, Age > 28 & Age < 24 & Hometown != New York)
```

Comment: Akbar and R18 thanks , but this code doesn't fit.  I want that the first row stays, not disappear

Answer (score 0):

Building subsets, remember that:

- When you want a variable to take an specific value (for example "New York"):

`subset(x, Hometown=="New York")`

- When you want a variable not to take an specific value (for example "New York")

`subset(x, Hometown!="New York")`

**Important**: the given value if it is a character, between " ", if desired a value double equal (`==`), if not desired (`!=`)

Answer (score 0):

For your statement "The Person must be under 28 years but older than 24 years", following should be the code

```
xnew <- subset(x, Hometown == "New York" & Age < 28 & Age > 24)
```

Comment: Thanks Anish, but if I use this code, also Row 4 disappears. But I want that Row 4 stays, because it is in the "age-rule". But I also want that Row 1 stays , because it is in the "hometown rule". Or I am just confused and overlooked something ?

Comment: This would work perfectly than --> xnew <- subset(x, Hometown == "New York"  | Age < 28 & Age > 24)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure by your wording, but it sounds like you want to grab the rows where the age is between 24 and 28, unless the hometown is New York, in which case grab that row regardless of the age. If this is correct, then you can use:

```
xnew <- subset(x, Age < 28 & Age > 24 | Hometown == "New York")
```